# How to generate a presigned URI that allow several HTTP methods (here : GET and HEAD)?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, pre-signed-url

I am using the aws s3 sdk for PHP, where you can easily generate presigned URIs like this :

```
$cmd = $my_S3Client->getCommand(
    'GetObject', [
        'Bucket' => 'my_bucket',
        'Key' => 'a_file.txt']);
$a_presigned_uri = $my_S3Client
    ->createPresignedRequest($cmd, $lifespan);
    ->getUri();
```

And this URI will only be queryable with a GET.

Now if I want to create a presigned URI queryable with a HEAD request, I just have to write the same code, but replacing

```
->getCommand('GetObject', [...])
```

with

```
->getCommand('HeadObject', [...])
```

Both of these work perfectly.

But I would like to be able to generate a presigned URI on which we can request both a GET or a HEAD request. And I don't know how to do this.

(Note: The objective all of this, is that my client could do a HEAD on the URI, in order to know the size of the file before he tries to download it. So if there is a possibility to generate a presigned URI with `'GetObject'` and then a way for the user to only retrieve the size of the file from this presigned URI, I'm also appreciating the answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now, You can only generate pre-signed URLs for One Object and One Client Method. This may change in future but who knows when.

Answer (score 2):

A `HEAD` request on an AWS S3 pre-signed URL generated for `GET` will result in a `403 Forbidden` response. You can, however, achieve the equivalent of a HEAD request on a pre-signed AWS S3 URL by doing a `GET` request with the `Range` header set as follows:

```
Range: bytes=0-0
```

This `GET` request will give you a successful `206 Partial Content` response, containing information about the S3 object without the object content itself. If you are interested in the size of the object, you will need to get this information from the `Content-Range` header in the response, as opposed to the `Content-Length` header as would be the case with the `HEAD` request (see example below).

Example output from Postman with both `HEAD` and `GET` (with Range Header) requests:

[image: s3-pre-signed-url-head-403-forbidden]

[image: S3 pre-signed URL GET request with Range header]

Finally, depending on where you are making the request from, you may need to update the CORS policy on the S3 bucket to expose the `Content-Range` header to clients if you wish to use it from client code. The policy will look something like this:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            ...
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            ...
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            ...
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "Accept-Ranges",  # Required
            "Content-Range",  # Required
            ...
        ],
        ...
    }
]
```