# S3 GET PreSigned URL 403 Forbidden from Viewing files in browsers

Tags: api, amazon-s3, file-upload, pre-signed-url

I am trying to view files from my S3 Bucket. I am a PreSigned URL and the react Package react-file-viewer.

Whenever I call the Signed URL through  react-file-viewer I get an error 403 forbidden. But if I copy and paste the Pre-Signed URL into my search bar I can view the file. I can also download the files and they open the data.

This is what my response is.

1. **Request Method:**

   HEAD
2. **Status Code:**

   403 Forbidden
3. **Remote Address:**

   xx.x.xx.xx..x..x
4. **Referrer Policy:**

   strict-origin-when-cross-origin

In my S3 bucket, I have this as my CORS header:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE",
            "HEAD",
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "x-amz-server-side-encryption",
            "x-amz-request-id",
            "x-amz-id-2"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

and my pre-signed URL is

```
var url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
          Bucket: BucketName,
          Key:  fileURLData[fileSpot].file_url,
          Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds,
           })
```

Does this look like an CORS issue or something to do with my S3 Bucket permissions?

Comment: You're presigning a GET request, that can't be used for a HEAD request.

Comment: So i change my pre-Signed url to headObject. But now its giving me a GET 400 error. I think my package is looking for bother a GET and a HEAD response. Here is another post talking about GET and HEAD response from a pre-Signed URL, but I don't know what the range is doing exactly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57149537/how-to-generate-a-presigned-uri-that-allow-several-http-methods-here-get-and